# How to ask moderators to delete a chat room?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, chat

Two private chat rooms were created in my name. I want to delete those two, but couldn't find a way to do that. After searching I learned that only moderators can do that.

Now how can I ask moderators to delete those rooms?

Links for those rooms are:

[link1](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17554/2012/10/10/10-12)
[link2](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17743/2012/10/9/10-11)

Comment: i(also google translate) dont understand which languages are you using in second link ?

Comment: @NullPointer - I think it is a [Telugu language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu_language)

Comment: @hims056 That's my mother tongue :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inactive or frozen chat rooms are automatically deleted after a certain time (7 days) ...

[image]

Comment: I think (not sure) 7 days...

Comment: @hims056 yup...also http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17554/2012/10/10/10-12 loled me

Comment: If a room is no longer relevant yet actively attracting people, they can also flag it for moderator attention to be deleted. I went ahead and deleted the ones referenced, as that seemed to be the case.

Comment: Thank you @tinytimpost

Comment: See the second sentence of the image you posted.  Your first line doesn't mesh up completely with what you posted.  If the room has at least 15 messages by two users, it will not be deleted after seven days, your comment implies that after seven days, *any* inactive or frozen room will be deleted.  This is not the case.