# How to delete own comment in chat room?

Tags: support, chat

Is there a possibility to delete my own comment(s) I left in any random SE chat room?

P.S. I am not talking about this: [How to ask moderators to delete a chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159975/how-to-ask-moderators-to-delete-a-chat-room)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting your own message is limited to 120 seconds after posting it, same way as editing it. If you posted something by mistake and want to delete, you can do so for 2 minutes:

> [image]

Otherwise, only a diamond moderator can delete the chat message. If you want one of your messages deleted after the 2 minutes window, you should contact a moderator, best and most non intrusive way is flagging one of your own posts, choose "other", and in there explain what messages you want removed and why.