# As a moderator, when should I delete a chatroom as requested by a user?

Tags: discussion, chat, moderator-tools

There was a moderator flag in chat a while back asking a mod to delete a chatroom. The room in question only had messages from one user; evidently the matter had been worked out somewhere else. I know low-activity rooms [will be automatically deleted or frozen eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159975/295684), and another mod handled the flag before I poked around MSE, so I didn't do anything in this case.

Under what circumstances should I carry out a user's request for room deletion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they're the only one who has talked in the room, might as well go ahead and delete it.

If it's someone else's room, or if multiple people have been carrying on a conversation... I'd be a bit reluctant to do anything until I understood the situation.

As a rule, do what you can to help, and do whatever is going to hurt the fewest people... Especially if that means doing nothing at all.